# How do I compile with -J-Duser.language=en option in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Because I'm a Chinese,I use a Chinese OS,but I need the output to be in English when compiled  with Netbeans, so I need the compiler option  `-J-Duser.language=en` can work.

But when I modify the additional compiler options to `-J-Duser.language=en`, when building the output is

> "javac: invalid flag: -J-Duser.language=en"

but I can normally  use compiler options like `-version`,`-Xlint:uncheced` etc. in Netbeans. Additionally I can use `-J-Duser.language=en` javac option in command line,only can't use it in Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify nb_home/etc/netbeans.conf as it is described here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf changing the netbeans_default_options parameter. This modification will be available in all your netbeans projects.